# Trouble with Conducted Emissions testing

Tags: rf

I am having some trouble determining how to qualify some results I have been getting for some conducted emissions in my RF lab. I am testing a DC power supply to the standard shown here for category M with a spectrum analyzer. Anything above the line for category M is counted as a failure[image]
[image]

This is my result, my co-worker says that the test does not meet category M and states that this trend line here in purple is the limit but I don't see where he is getting this trend from. I'm not sure if I'm understanding the test properly but I do not see how on earth the product failed to meet this specification when the results are clearly down in the negative dbm. Am I correct in saying that this product meets the specifications for category M or does it fail and there is something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dBuA (microampere current) is an entirely different unit than dBm (output power) and coverting from dBuA to dBm isn't trivial (I cheat and use online calculators such as http://www.cantwellengineering.com/calculator/convert/dBuA). EMC standards often specify various details for how something should placed when measured. You can assume 50ohm impedance though. Then the 20dBuA limit would equal -53dBm, so the limits drawn on your spec screenshots look correct.

dBm is a logarithmic scale in relation to the linear mW scale, where everything below 0dBm means less than 1mW. The 20dBμA/-53dBm limit is equal to ~5uW so this is a tough requirement. Your device is clearly above that limit, so your co-worker is correct - it doesn't fulfil the requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

> Anything below the line for category M is counted as a failure

No, it's the other way around: anything *above* the line for category M is counted as a failure. Between 1 and 30 MHz the noise is too high: it exceeds the limit set by the blue curve. That is a failure.

> the results are clearly down in the negative dbm.

dBm are relative. Just because the value is negative doesn't mean that they are OK. The values are negative because they're less than a milliWatt, but they are still higher than the allowed limit.

Comment: I don't know what the left hand scale in the 'scope trace is supposed to be.  The CE requirement is in dBuA.  It doesn't make sense to me that the 'scope scale would be in dBm.

Comment: And dBuA is just a way of specifying a relative CM (common mode) current relative to 1 uA.

Comment: @SteveSh if the system impedance is known, then current, voltage, and power are all interchangeable measurements. It seems likely to me that the co-worker either knows or assumes a 50 ohm impedance, which means 20dBuA is equal to -53 dBm as he has drawn on the screenshot. Maybe a current measurement makes sense in the testing context? some sort of inductive loop to read emissions? I don't think dBuA is necessarily a common mode measurement either, just a unit for measuring any general current.

Comment: How does the trend workout though? Im new to rf and I'm unsure as to how he came up that result. Id ask him myself but he decided to just walk out of the job and now I'm trying to piece together his results with almost no documentation. If the reference level was different would that have affected the result?

Comment: @Brandon - Yes.  But CM currents are usually what causes a device or installation to fail CE testing.  It only takes 5 uA of CM current to fail an FCC Part 15 Class B compliance test.

Comment: @SteveSh You're entirely right. I missed that it was not radiated emissions testing. However, am I right in my [reading](https://www.egr.msu.edu/emrg/sites/default/files/content/module11_conducted.pdf) that the FCC specifies 50 Ohms as the stabilized impedance for the LISN used to measure the conducted emissions for both the neutral and hot lines? If so, the dBuA to dBm conversion is still correct.

Comment: I think you're right about the LISN use for CE on power lines.  But CE outages can be caused by CM currents on any cable that leaves or enters the box, not just power cables.